# why doesn't this style html work

Tags: html, css

In the below following HTML the `<b>` is not working for making the "6" bold.  any ideas why?

```
<h2 style="margin:1px;padding:0;color:#333333;font-family:verdana;font-size:85%"> I am <b> 6 </b> years old today </h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct bold tag is `<strong>` not `<b>`. But h2 are bold on most browsers by default, which means you should make your h2 non bold first.

Comment: Add font-weight:normal on it.

Comment: Depending of the font you are using, you might also use numbers to get more than just bold and non bold. The supported values are 100, 200... until 900. But I think most web safe fonts have only bold and non bold.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the whole string is already bold as it is `h2`. Try to change it to italic and see if it works. If so try copy the string to something like OOo or MS Word and check if it is already bold.

If it is bold so make h2 not bold by adding `font-weight:normal` to h2 style.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum for styling the header tags. 
See the official documentation with example here:

[H2 Tags and Styling](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5)